# Python Classification - data structure

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to develop a classifier for documents. I am relatively new to python and I am trying to figure out what the best/standard way of creating the storage structure. I am looking to introduce the dataset with machine learning algos.

I am ingesting txt files and I was thinking to have one column hold the entire document content and the second column hold the class(0-1) in my case. I initially tried creating a list of lists - such that list `["the skye is blue",1]["the sky is grey",1]["the sky is red",0]`.

I was also trying to create a pandas Dataframe because I thought its structure may be more suitable for data manipulation.

Comment: What was the problem with the nested list?

Comment: @RouvenB The problem is that I developed it such that the first part is the content and the second is the class ["the sky is blue",1]. I would be impossible to train this dataset as is for my understanding as there is no way of selecting the second object of the first list (the class). An I wrong? If I am looking to supervised learning this structure I believe is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

> I was also trying to create a pandas Dataframe because I thought its structure may be more suitable for data manipulation.

I would go with that. Given that the goal is to build and train a classifier you will need to extract/compute some features from the text of the files. When you decide to do that the capability to easily generate and add new variables to a Dataframe will come in handy.

However, it also depends on the size of the data you will be crunching. If you will have massive data you should research different concepts and frameworks (for instance [TensorFlow](http://www.tensorflow.org/))

Comment: Most examples that I've seen ingest a CSV file or a txt file that is delimited by "white space". In my opinion, delimiting a txt file with 'white space' when doing data mining is not the way to go as you can loose valuable information, as the tokenisation of words and bi-grams is not as clean as if you would 'open the file' into a variable and then tokenise.

Comment: I am not sure I got your comment, but regarding the comment above in the OP where you say >  there is no way of selecting the second object of the first list (the class). well, there is, it is something that you can learn by following some python tutorials for beginners, try it out and repost if you find troubles. Anyway I find it easier to manipulate and compute on the data using Pandas, although you still need to know the very same basics about data structures in Python.

Comment: I've been reading up on tutorials of Pandas etc. I am still struggling with  the following and I just can't keep get my head around it. I am reading a directory of plain txt files with the following command in a for loop: `pd.read_csv('//filedirectory'+i ,sep="\t" , quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None, names=['message', 'class')` into 'list_'. The result is a number of lists equal to the number of files in the directory. Each list consists of X amount of rows breaking down every file to numerous rows.I want a Dataframe in which one row holds the entire message. Any ideas?
             `

Comment: This post is too general and is about the opinion on something, on which I already gave mine. For that I would advise creating a new post, describing what you tried to do, posting also the code of what you have done so far.